# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no j2pkcs11 in java.library.path in java6

Tags: java, keystore, e-token

I'm trying to use a eToken to sign a pdf file using a java application I wrote. I'm using a windows 7 64 bit edition with java 6.0.30.

When I run the application I'm getting an exception saying

```
Exception in thread "signer" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no j2pkcs11 in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1738)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1028)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11$1.run(PKCS11.java:88)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.<clinit>(PKCS11.java:86)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.<init>(SunPKCS11.java:281)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.<init>(SunPKCS11.java:90)
    at com.greytip.cougar.pdfsigner.PdfSigner.getProvider(PdfSigner.java:364)
```

But when I looked up the `j2pkcs11.dll` file is available to jdk 1.5 but not available in my jdk 1.6 64 bit.

Is to anything to do with java security policy since the exception is coming inside `AccessController`, ie the dll is inside a protected directory inside windows 7?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like pkcs11 is not implemented in any of the 64-bit versions of java. It is only available in the 32-bit version.

So I'm planning to install a 32-bit version of java and work with it.

Comment: In Java8 pkcs11 support is fixed

Answer (score 0):

I Had similar issue and tested signing code on jre-8u31-windows-x64 and had success. So i suggest to use this java version. In my scenario I had to sign an xml file which is around 196MB in size for a government application called e-defter. To sign this file java needs memory (HEAP) at around 3GB. I could get this memory with 64 bit java.